# Calculating $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{2^n-n^2}$

Tags: calculus

I'm having quite hard time proving the following statement:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{2^n-n^2}=2$$

I though about using the squeeze theorem. So I started to look for upper and lower expressions and quickly found an upper limit to the expression,

$$\sqrt[n]{2^n-n^2}<\sqrt[n]{2^n}=2$$

However, I found it very difficult to find the lower limit.
Help would be appreciated!.

Answer (score 5):

$$
\sqrt[n\,]{2^n-n^2}=2\sqrt[n]{1-2^{-n}n^2}\ge 2\sqrt[n]{1-\tfrac14}
$$
for all $n$ where $2^n>4n^2$, which is true for $n\ge 10$.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response!

Answer (score 3):

For large enough $n$, we have $n^2\lt 2^{n-1}$. Thus for large enough $n$ we have 
$$\sqrt[n]{2^n-n^2}\gt \sqrt[n]{2^n-2^{n-1}}=2^{(n-1)/n}.$$

Comment: Thank you. It is very clean and elegant.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

To use squeezing is a chance, but also consider that $a_n = 2^n-n^2$ gives a positive sequence for $n\geq 4$, and that quite obviously $\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=2$, hence $\sqrt[n]{a_n}\to 2$ by the [ratio/root test](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/RootTest.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Notice, $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{2^n+n^2}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(2^n+n^2\right)^{1/n}=\lim_{n\to \infty}2\left(1+\frac{n^2}{2^n}\right)^{1/n}$$
since, $\frac{n^2}{2^n}<1$, hence using binomial expansion of $\left(1+\frac{n^2}{2^n}\right)^{1/n}$
$$=2\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1+\frac{n^2}{n\cdot 2^n}+\ldots \right)$$
$$=2\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1+\frac{n}{2^n}+\ldots \right)$$
since, $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n}{2^n}=0$
$$=2\left(1+0 \right)=\color{red}{2}$$