# Solving Limit $\sqrt[n]{2^n-n^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I have to solve the following limit:

$$\lim\limits _{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{2^n-n^2}$$

I thought about the following trick and I don't know if it's correct:

$$\lim\limits _{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{2^n-n^2} = 2 \cdot \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{1-\frac{n^2}{2^n}}$$

Since the inner limit equals to $1$ - from limit arithmetic, it seems legit for me to say that the whole limit equals $2$.

Is it?

Comment: yesd you are right, the searched Limit is $2$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner - thanks! Is the way of solving is correct?

Comment: Yes this is correct. If you want to make it rigorous show that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{x} = 1$ for any real $x>0$. From there you can conclude that also $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{a_n} = 1$ for any bounded sequence $a_n$ of positive reals.

Comment: if you have proved that $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{1-\frac{n^2}{2^n}}=1$$ then is you way correct

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculating $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{2^n-n^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1515063/calculating-lim-n-to-infty-sqrtn2n-n2)